# Integration of $\min \{x-[x] , -x-[-x]\} $where $[x]$ is floor function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How to calculate integration of $ \min \{x-[x] , -x-[-x]\}$ (where $[x]$ is floor function)  without drawing graph

[image]

Comment: i want to calculate it without graph. i have solved graphically.

Comment: "where x is greatest integer function greater than or equal to x": you either take the least integer greater or equal to $x$ ("ceiling function") or you take the largest integer smaller or equal to $x$ ("floor function"). The largest integer larger than something does not make sense.

Comment: Yeah  Thats correct, I think he means greatest integer less than or equal to x.

Comment: Try splitting the integral up into cases (e.g. for $-2\le x\le 1,\; -1\le x\le0,\;\dots$). You don’t need to care about the value on the boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphically it can be calculated as below. Without graph i'm unable to solve this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x-[x] = \{x\}$ where $\{x\}$ is the fraction part of $x$. Also note that $\{x\}$ is periodic with period $1$ because:

$$\color{red}{\{x+1\}}= x+1-[x+1] = x -[x] = \color{red}{\{x\}} $$

Thus your integrand converts to $\min\{ \{x\}, \{-x\}\}$.  This function is periodic too again with period $1$, so we just have to analyse in integer interval of length $1$.

Therefore value of integral is $4$ times the value on $(0,1)$

$$I = \int_{-2}^{2} \min\{ \{x\}, \{-x\}\} = 4\int_{0}^{1}  \min\{ \{x\}, \{-x\}\}$$

For $0\lt x \lt 1$ we have that $\{x\} = x$ and $\{-x\} = 1-x$. Thus for $x \in (0, 0.5)$ integrand is $x$ and from $[0.5, 1)$ integrand is $1-x$. Area of this one unit is found to be $\boxed {1/4}$.

Hence $I = 1.$

**Note:** For *fraction part* function, refer *Graham et. al definition* here: [Fractional Part - Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalPart.html)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)